# add python function to specific action odoo

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-11

i want to add this function to action 'hr_holidays.open_allocation_holidays' to make 'holiday_status_id' field change every time when dynamically based on 'employee_id'

```
@api.onchange('employee_id')
def change_leave_type(self):
    for holiday_type in self:
        if holiday_type.env.uid == holiday_type.user_id.id and not holiday_type.env.user.has_group(
                'hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_user'):
            allocate_type = holiday_type.env['hr.holidays.status'].search([('name', '=', 'Compensatory Days')]).id
            return {'domain': {'holiday_status_id': [('id', '=', allocate_type)]}}
        elif holiday_type.env.user.has_group(
                'hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_user') and not holiday_type.env.user.has_group(
                'hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_manager'):
            ids = []
            allocation_types = holiday_type.env['hr.holidays.status'].search([])
            for allocate in allocation_types:
                if allocate.name != 'Unpaid':
                    ids.append(allocate.id)
            return {'domain': {'holiday_status_id': [('id', '=', ids)]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a generated domain to the field by adding the domain-get function to the domain of that field.

```
@api.model
def _get_holiday_status_id_domain(self):
    if self.env.uid == self.user_id.id and not self.env.user.has_group('hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_user'):
        allocate_type = self.env['hr.holidays.status'].search([('name', '=', 'Compensatory Days')], limit=1)
        return [('id', '=', allocate_type.id)]
    elif self.env.user.has_group('hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_user') and not self.env.user.has_group('hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_manager'):
        allocation_types = self.env['hr.holidays.status'].search([('name', '!=', 'Unpaid')])
        return [('id', 'in', allocation_types.mapped('id'))]

holiday_status_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='hr.holidays.status', 
    string='Holiday Status',
    domain=_get_holiday_status_id_domain,
    # and your other settings
    )
```

Comment: your solution is so good domain work fine ..... 
but still a problem it affects on 'leaves request' action and 'allocate request' action (because they load the same view { has same External ID})
thanks so much

Comment: If you only need to alter the behaviour of allocation, the domain generation function and `domain=_get_holiday_status_id_domain` only need to be added to `HolidaysAllocation` class under `hr_leave_allocation.py`; if it is added to the `HolidaysRequest` class under `hr_leave.py` it will affect leave requests as well.

Comment: i use odoo 11 ..... there is no HolidaysAllocation class in leaves module just 'hr.holidays' class and 'hr.holiday.status' class

Comment: You can simply add a `if` statement at begining, return `[(1, '=', 1)]` under certain conditions, there must be a field telling if it is a leave request or allocation request.

Comment: there is 'type' field in hr.holidays model :
type = fields.Selection([
            ('remove', 'Leave Request'),
            ('add', 'Allocation Request')
])
but it doesn't work on domain function